# How do I setup up and deploy Kubeflow with Codefresh

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, codefresh

Currently, I deploy python scripts on Kubernetes using Codefresh. I'm looking to incorporate Kubeflow into the deployment plan to get all the Kubeflow goodies such as the UI and all but I'm a little clueless on how to start or where to look.

The docs for Kubeflow mainly only cover setting up with Google Cloud Platform only. Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these [instructions](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/k8s/kfctl-k8s-istio/) to install kubeflow on any existing kubernetes cluster, regardless of whether you are running on GCP or any other platform.

These steps can be converted into a codefresh pipeline like any other set of commands. If you need help with that let me know, we use codefresh and I'm well versed with there pipeline files.